# How to view bind <merge> and include tag with id

Tags: android, kotlin, merge, include, android-viewbinding

Im trying to get layouts with merge root tag to work with view binding. I have a main_acticity that include the merge layout with an id

this is my merge_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/merge_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/test"/>

  
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/merge_test_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/merge_test_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</merge>
```

this is my include_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   //---->My Stuff<----

    <include
        android:id="@+id/merge_layout"
        layout="@layout/merge_layout" />


</FrameLayout>
```

And the main activity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = IncludeLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        binding.mergeLayout.mergeTestButton.setOnClickListener {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "it work!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Runtime exception: `Missing required view with ID: mergeLayout`

I want to know if is there any way to bind merge using an id in the include tag, like the example

Comment: Try calling this  way binding.mergeTestButton.setOnClickListener {}

Answer (score 0):

When you use a merge tag in the root of a layout that you're going to include, don't put the id in the include tag.

activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <include layout="@layout/marge_layout" />
    
</FrameLayout>
```

your marge layout which you went to include in activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/merge_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_app"/> 
 
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/merge_test_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/merge_test_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</merge>
```

then your activity code like below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("AndroidCustomToast")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityTempBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        val margeLayout = MargeLayoutBinding.bind(binding.root)
        margeLayout.mergeTestButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "it work!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to bind views putting the id in include tag?

Comment: I don't know any other way